# Handling swipe gesture on UIWebview

Tags: iphone

I want to load gmail and yahoo on two individual UIwebview's and pan/swipe between those two views. But the scroll/pan does not work since Gmail and Yahoo handle swipe gestures inside the browser for performing their own functionality. Like on Gmail swipe "Archive" is the action. For yahoo, on the swipe "Delete", "Mark favorite" etc are the features shown. I am able to successfully

Please let me know if my main controller can receive swipe events so that i can swipe/pan/scroll between those two web views. Also my app should support App store guide lines.

Regards,
Prasad

Answer (score 1):

Following solution will work in this situation.
1. Take a UIView
2. Add smaller Webview as a subview to the UIview
3. Add swipe gesture Recognizer to UIView.
Now Panning on the View area will solve the problem and It will also support AppStore Guide Lines.
You can put an image showing the Arrow to swipe/pan.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is more of an option or work around. So are you concluding that since Gmail and Yhaoo have already captured the swipe/pan gestures for their internal features, there is no way my controller beneath the webview could receive the swipe/pan gestures?

Comment: You are using UIWebView which is a native iOS component.. You have mentioned Gmail and Yahoo above they are having Native app Developed on the controller.. There are no webviews and loading HTML pages..

Answer (score 0):

You can receive the swipe gestures within the main controller, then pass them as needed into the uiwebviews via javasacript.  Here is an example:

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(swipeRightAction:)];
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    swipeRight.delegate = self;

    swipeRight.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    swipeRight.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
    [webView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
```

Then...

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
     return YES;
}

- (void)swipeRightAction:(id)ignored
{

    // Send javascript into web view
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert('Swipe right');"];


    //[webView goBack]; // or just navigate back in web view
}
```