# WebView in Scroll View

Tags: ios, webview, uiscrollview, xcode5

I have a view controller with only a ScrollView that takes up the whole screen.  In the first "page/view", I have a WebView.  The WebView works just fine and I am able to scroll up and down the website.  However, when I try to directly swipe left to get to the next page, it does nothing.  However, if I press down on the screen go slightly up or down first and swipe left, I am able to get to the next page.  I have researched all day and I am about to give up.  Any ideas?  It seems like the direct swipe left action is retrieved by the WebView and not the Scroll View but I do not know how else to get past this.  Please help!

Comment: I'm not sure if you will be able to find a solution to this since the WebView needs to be able to capture touch events and pass it on to javascript. But you could try subclassing UIWebView and capturing the events before it goes to javascript...

Comment: check those link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187274/detect-swipe-gesture-in-uiwebview      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711208/handling-swipe-gesture-on-uiwebview

Comment: I tried adding gestures to the Scrollview and the WebView but it doesn't seem to recognize it.  It still seems like the WebView is "retrieving" the gesture instead of the gesturerecognizer. =(

Comment: It's so strange.  I noticed that this issue only happens so far with www.cellucor.com.  I've tested my code with any other random sites and the scroll works just fine.  strange...